# how to highlight user specified words in vscode

Tags: ide, visual-studio-code

I need to have my vscode highlight specific words so I can leave different notes in the code and easily see them when I need to, for example: Note: with the color green and DEBUG with color red and so on.

Comment: Also look at  the `Highlight` extension, see https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-highlight.  It has the advantage of using multiple capture groups on a line and separately styling those if you desire.  Although it doesn't sound like you are looking for that...yet.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**UPDATE Jun/2023** Thanks to Andre Greeff for his comment, "quick 2023 update: the original "TODO Highlight" by Wayou has not seen any updates since 2019 and appears as though it may be abandoned.. for anybody visiting this going forward, you should check out "[TODO Highlight V2](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jgclark.vscode-todo-highlight)", maintained by Jonathan Clark". All the instructions and keywords should work the same. I'll be testing them and if I find any changes I'll update this post accordingly.
Cheers!

**Edit Jun/2022** I've added both *"todohighlight.include"* and *"todohighlight.exclude"* keys with some sample values for, files/file name patterns, to include and exclude on the highlighting. Cheers!

**Edit Jun/2021** It's been a while since I published this post. I've updated the sample for more detailed highlighting. Post your comments down below if you need clarifications. Cheers!

Download and install [TODO Highlight](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wayou.vscode-todo-highlight)  extension. After you download and install the extension, make sure you restart your VSCode. Now please follow the following steps in order to add custom keyword highlighting in your code.

- On windows hold down Ctrl + Shift and on mac Command + Shift,
  then press the key P.

a command line opens up.

- On the command line type "open    settings" and click on
  "Preferences: open settings".

Settings window will open.

- under the "search setting" input on the right handside look for the
  three dots "..." and click on it.
- Click on "Open settings.json".

"User Settings" tab will open.
It contains a split screen window. on the left side you see the defualt settings and on the right side you see the user settings

- in the "search settings" type "*todohighlight.keywords*"

you will see `"todohighlight.keywords": []`.

- Hover over it with your mouse

a little pen will show up on its left side

- click on it

you'll see a drop-down select menu opens.

- click on "Replace in settings".

you can now see `"todohighlight.keywords": []` in the right pannel window (USER SETTINGS).

This is an array that contains json objects such as following:

```
"todohighlight.keywords": [
    {
        "text": "todo:",
        "color": "#000000",
        "backgroundColor": "DarkKhaki",
        "overviewRulerColor": "DarkKhaki",
        "border": "1px solid DarkKhaki",
        "borderRadius": "3px",
        "isWholeLine": false
    },
    {
        "text": "note:",
        "color": "#000000",
        "backgroundColor": "#72824E",
        "overviewRulerColor": "#72824E",
        "border": "1px solid #72824E",
        "borderRadius": "3px",
        "isWholeLine": false
    },
    {
        "text": "System.debug",
        "color": "#000000",
        "backgroundColor": "STEELBLUE",
        "overviewRulerColor": "STEELBLUE",
        "border": "1px solid STEELBLUE",
        "borderRadius": "3px",
        "isWholeLine": false
    },
    {
        "text": "system.debug",
        "color": "#000000",
        "backgroundColor": "STEELBLUE",
        "overviewRulerColor": "STEELBLUE",
        "border": "1px solid STEELBLUE",
        "borderRadius": "3px",
        "isWholeLine": false
    },
    {
        "text": "console.log",
        "color": "#000000",
        "backgroundColor": "STEELBLUE",
        "overviewRulerColor": "STEELBLUE",
        "border": "1px solid STEELBLUE",
        "borderRadius": "3px",
        "isWholeLine": false
    },
    {
        "text": "|DEBUG|",
        "color": "#000000",
        "backgroundColor": "#72848A",
        "overviewRulerColor": "#72848A",
        "border": "1px solid #72848A",
        "borderRadius": "3px",
        "isWholeLine": true
    },
    {
        "text": "attention:",
        "color": "white",
        "backgroundColor": "red",
        "border": "1px solid red",
        "borderRadius": "3px",
        "isWholeLine": false
    },
    {
        "text": "debug:",
        "color": "white",
        "backgroundColor": "red",
        "border": "1px solid red",
        "borderRadius": "3px",
        "isWholeLine": false
    }
],
"todohighlight.include": [
    "**/*.js",
    "**/*.jsx",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    "**/*.html",
    "**/*.php",
    "**/*.css",
    "**/*.scss"
],
"todohighlight.exclude": [
    "**/node_modules/**",
    "**/bower_components/**",
    "**/dist/**",
    "**/build/**",
    "**/.vscode/**",
    "**/.github/**",
    "**/_output/**",
    "**/*.min.*",
    "**/*.map",
    "**/.next/**"
]
```

If you're not familiar with json notation copy the content of "todohighligh.keywords" from the sample above and past it to your "user settings" window in between the two `[]` brackets. you can change the values on the left side of `:` colon in between `""` double quotes. if you would like to add more than two keywords simply add a comma after the last closing curly bracket `}` in your "user settings" and copy/past one json object (which is from one `{` open bracket to the first closing `}` bracket) and then change its content. you can add as many keywords as you'd like to.

> MAKE SURE YOU SAVE THE FILE by holding down Ctrl(windows) / command(mac) and press the key "s" or from the menu bar go to File ->
> Save

Comment: These are great instructions. They were very thorough and helped me a lot

Comment: Is there a way to limit this highlighting behavior only on some files? E.g. I would like to only highlight these words in ".log" extension files.

Comment: @kocica, yes it's possible and I've updated the sample json with the two new keywords. I hope it helps. Thanks!

Comment: quick 2023 update: the original "TODO Highlight" by Wayou has not seen any updates since 2019 and appears as though it may be abandoned.. for anybody visiting this going forward, you should check out ["TODO Highlight V2"](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jgclark.vscode-todo-highlight), maintained by Jonathan Clark.

Answer (score 2):

My answer may not apply your scene, but if someone wants to highlight any word,I prefer this plugin:

[image]

The following options can be configured

```
highlightwords.colors: this is an array of light/dark pairs for respective theme types, you can have as few or as many as you like

highlightwords.box: show highlights as a box around the selections if true, set highlight as background color if false

highlightwords.defaultMode: the initial mode when initialized. 0=default, 1=whole word, 2=ignore case, 3=whole word and ignore case

highlightwords.showSidebar provides a view in the explorer window for searching, changing options and removing highlights
```

Comment: Could you provide a link instead of just a screenshot?

Comment: https://github.com/rsbondi/highlight-words